# Xcode 8 Code signing error

Tags: certificate, signing, ios10, xcode8

I have Xcode 8 installed on OSX el Captain.

I have a stickers bundle which runs on simulator. However, when I build it on me errors as below:

***Check dependencies
Signing for "StickerPackExtension" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'***

***Showing Recent Errors Only
Signing for "StickerPackExtension" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.***

***Code signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'***

I have tried creating the certificates again, clean build, restarting Xcode but the error is still there. I have also tried 'automatic manage signing' and changed the settings manually as well.

Please help!

Comment: i am not using cocoaPods. its just a sticker package where i have inserted assets (pictures). That's it.

Comment: Same issue; unable to make signing work for stickerpackextension.

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was selecting the Signing Profile Team for **both** Targets: The extension and the wrapper application.

It's not obvious, but if you open the drop-down to the left of `General` with the name of your app and select `StickerPackExtension`, you can then set the Team for the extension.

Source:
[Apple Dev Forums: Stickers on Xcode 8 development team error](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62975)

Answer (score 0):

Did you select signing certificate for all of your pods (if you use CocoaPods) and all your frameworks included in solution?

Comment: i am not using cocoaPods. its just a sticker package where i have inserted assets (pictures). That's it.

Comment: according to error message, one of your dependencies isn't signed

Comment: It works fine with Xcode 7. its ony Xcode 8 which is displaying this error.

Comment: I know, I had the same error, after setting up all related projects all works fine

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to `Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts`. Select the Apple Developer ID that you use for that App. Then select the `team` in the box at the bottom that displays the teams. Tap on the `View Details` button and then on the new screen tap the button `Download All Profiles`. This will re-download your profiles.

That fixed it for me.